# Bootstrap CSS not fully loading

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, view

I downloaded codeigniter fresh from their website.

After having this running smoothly I wanted to add bootstrap.

I made an assets folder in the codeigniter root folder (where application, system and user guide is).

At assets I made a css folder and a JS folder. I put all the bootstrap css inside css and the same for js.

Now when I try to use anything from bootstrap it won't show properly.

I checked the console and it's not giving me any error.

This is my home view code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css') ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-grid.css') ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-reboot.css') ?>">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.js')?>"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">test</button>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

and it shows me the page like this:

[image: Link to my image]

Comment: Did you set the base url in config.php you need to.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes i added a base url! I used in in my code, and its not giving me a error

Comment: Can you reach assets with link or it's 404 error or anything?!

Comment: @Yahya i can reach assets! When i remove the bootstrap css the layout changes , but when i load the bootstrap css its not the full one, like on the picture

Comment: Give it a try with loading bootstrap from cdn

Comment: @Yahya What is cdn? I tried it with the online link and then it works like a charm... but i want it offline

Comment: And you sure that your css file isn't corrupted or anything?!

Comment: @Yahya i already downloaded bootstrap like 5 times

Comment: Let's save that online file that worked for you and just use it?!

Comment: @Yahya ill try that

Comment: Are you loading the url helper? If you don't then `base_url()` doesn't work.

Comment: @ourmandave yep! Else you get an error

Comment: There is no error because your HTML is correct. You're just getting an navbar with a 'test' button fixed to the top of the page. There is no other content to show.

Comment: @ourmandave im getting a peefect nav bar when im using the online css file , when im using the offline file im not getting the navbar !

Comment: Have you looked at the content of your offline css files? Sometimes I download a file and it turns out to be a copy of the html of the download page instead of the actual file I wanted.

Comment: I have run your page and the only file it needs for that example to "Appear" correctly is the bootstrap.css file. So Simple check - view your HTML Source in your browser and eyeball the actual links being generated... if you click on the bootstrap.css link you should see the css file.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw my bootstrap.css loads perfectly, and it's the right one...

Comment: @PieterDuchateau so the page is displaying correctly now?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw no it's not loading perfectly , but it's loading the right bootstrap.css file

Comment: @PieterDuchateau Well apart from there being any other strange funnies - your bootstrap.css file is not loading correctly... If you view the HTML and View the link and click on it - do you actually see the bootstrap.css file appear in the browser? It's a common quick, lazy - does it work - trick.

Comment: Better yet - can you paste the actual generated HTML that loads the bootstrap.css file?

Comment: copy pasted the online bootstrap and renamed my bootstrap.css to test.css , now it's working ! thanks for the support guys !

Comment: @PieterDuchateau what is the "online bootstrap" Have you bailed and just used an external link?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw took the online link; copynpasted the code inside a css file

Comment: So that indicates that your downloaded bootstrap.css was corrupted/Not Quite Right? Hmmm well if thats what works then....

Comment: @TimBrownlaw ill just call this strange ... dont think the file was corrupted but yeah it works now! Sofware sometimes does strange things